I am writing a racist character in the 1960s. She uses the N-word. An editor told me that this was not appropriate in 2024
Characters are at a dance. Referring to one of the musicians (who later becomes an important character), Character # 1 say's to character # 2:

“He’s a nigger, and a hillbilly, for god’s sake. You didn’t tell me that. This is supposed to be a cowboy dance.” On the bandstand, Jess noticed me, and nodded.

Character # 2 replies:

“Max! They are not . . . that. They’re Mexican and Asian, or something. But why shouldn’t they be . . . Negroes?” I waved back.


You haven't posed a specific question for the site. What about this situation are you wanting help with?

"Negro’s"  - you don't need an apostrophe there.

I cannot imagine anybody bothering to say "and a hillbilly" when they've already called someone the N word.  People didn't differentiate a great deal.  Once they'd dropped the N-bomb, they wouldn't have considered any other characteristic of the person - the N is all the description they'd need.

It is inappropriate in 2024 to call a person of sub-Saharan origin a "nigger", but if you set your book at a time and place where that was how people talked – the 1960s, for example, or a group of racists today – and you want to portrait that culture accurately, then of course it is not only appropriate but necessary to reproduce their speech truthfully.
In social media, the convention today is to censor offensive words using asterisks (e.g. "n****r"), but since that is not what people did in the past or do in racist circles, putting this convention in their mouths would be confusing.
Nevertheless, if your publisher demands that you remove that word so as not to offend their customers, you must, if you want to publish with them, and you should do so gracefully. Publishers want to avoid anything that might negatively impact their sales (see for example the controversy surrounding Mark Twain's Adventures of Huckleberry Finn), and as a professional writer of popular fiction you have to be able to adapt to the circumstances. Explain your reasoning for your usage to your editor and ask them, what they propose.

It's rare to see asterisk censorship in fiction (though it does get used in comics), but you will see other techniques, such as allusion: "Then she called the man a word that mama wouldn't much like me to repeat."

I strongly agree with Ben: of course it is not only appropriate but necessary to reproduce historical speech truthfully… and I very sadly notice too many, if not most modern publishers and editors have kow-towed to the woke rules which say that's irrelevant and truth must always be subservient to particular sensibilities.

You have no actual question, and an anonymous user12345, but for everyone else...
Historical Fiction is not LARPing
Your story is set in the 1960s.
The readers are not.
You don't get to change that. Your story has to 'play' in the reader's 21st Century head.
There is a legitimate debate to be had on all sorts of topics in Historical Fiction, but that's not how the OP was tagged.
TV Tropes: Deliberate Values Dissonance is a good list of intents and pitfalls when choosing how to represent the past.
Defend it

What is the purpose of the scene?

Is it conveying information that's new to the reader?

Is there a    payoff later? What is the 'sequel' to this scene?

Does it 'turn'
(progress) the story in some way?

How is this scene a barometer of    the MC's arc at this point in the
story?


Fix it
From what I can perceive of your 'scenario', Character A approaches Character B and says something obvious but in a crude way. Character B agrees because the fact is obvious.
There is no conflict. It feels like a strawman inserted to contrast the MC. You can do more with this scene than rely on a one-word cliché to do the characterization and worldbuilding.
Subtext and reader expectations
Character B corrects A by substituting the (outdated) label used by B's class/peer-group, while normalizing the general homogeny/insulation with a scattershot of other un-sure race labels.
The subtext suggests (and I'm being generous) the author's intent is to make the reader aware of an idealogical difference between A and B while also showing how they are similar in actual behavior and thinking by 'othering' these ... Mexican-Asian-Hillbilly-Negros. Did Jew forget anyone?
'Asian' would be anachronistic in the 1960s, if there is some appeal to historical accuracy implied in the OP.
Or don't fix it
No advice here, really. I'm sure you can find another publisher, and the publisher can find another author.
